# Restrictions on Type in dart

Tags: dart, types

So, basically I need to create restrictions of which types can be used in a `Type` variable, something like this:

```
class ElementFilter<T extends Element> {
    final Type<T> elementType; // What I want is something like Type<T>, but Type does not have a generic parameter
    ElementFilter(this.elementType);
}

List<T> filterElements<T extends Element>(ElementFilter<T> element) {
    return elements.where((el) => _isOfType(el, element.type)).toList();
}

filterElements(ElementFilter(ClassThatExtendsElement)); // Would work fine
filterELements(ElementFilter(String)); // Error, String does not extends Element
```

So it would only be possible to create `ElementFilter`s with types that extend `Element`. Is this possible in some way?

Comment: Are you sure that your "Works fine" example actually works?  `Type<T> elementType` is not legal since `Type` is not a generic class.  I presume that you mean `Type elementType`, but then `T` would be completely unused in `ElementFilter`, and its construction argument would be unconstrained.

Comment: Sorry, I think I gave a bad example, what I want is something like a `Type<T>`, but `Type` does not have a generic type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you probably want:

```dart
/// Example usage: ElementFilter<ClassThatExtendsElement>();
class ElementFilter<T extends Element> {
  final Type elementType;
  ElementFilter() : elementType = T;
}
```

Unfortunately, there's no way to make the generic type argument non-optional.  You will have to choose between having a required argument and having a compile-time constraint on the `Type` argument.

Dart doesn't support algebraic types, so if you additionally want to support a finite set of types that don't derive from `Element`, you could make specialized derived classes and require that clients use those instead of `ElementFilter`.  For example:

```dart
class StringElementFilter extends ElementFilter<Element> {
  @override
  final Type elementType = String;
}
```

(You also could create a `StringElement` class that extends `Element` if you want, but at least for this example, it would serve no purpose.)

Comment: Thank you so much! Sometimes I forget that generic types in dart can used in runtime as well, but I didn't know that you could set them to a variable

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend not using `Type` objects at all. Ever. They're pretty useless, and if you have the type available as a *type parameter*, you're always better off. (The type variable can always be converted to a `Type` object, but it can also be actually *useful* in many other ways).

Example:

```dart
class ElementFilter<T extends Element> {
  bool test(Object? element) => element is T;
  Iterable<T> filterElements(Iterable<Object?> elements) => 
      elements.whereType<T>();
}

List<T> filterElements<T extends Element>(ElementFilter<T> filter) =>
    filter.filterElements(elements).toList();

filterElements(ElementFilter<ClassThatExtendsElement>()); // Would work fine
filterElements(ElementFilter<String>()); // Error, String does not extends Element
```